# Office 365 New-InboxRule Powershell script

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm trying to create a little script to quickly create simple inbox rules on Office 365 using PowerShell. Thus far I have the following syntax that is getting hung up by what I have in the  '-MoveToFolder' parameter. I've started repeating steps so it's time to ask for help...

```
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$MoveToFolder = Read-Host -Prompt "Destination folder name"
$FromAddressContainsWords = Read-Host -Prompt "Sender info"
$UserEmailAddress = $UserCredential | %{$_.UserName}
Connect-MsolService -Credential $UserCredential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session -AllowClobber
New-MailboxFolder -Parent :\Inbox -Name "$MoveToFolder"
$MAlias = Get-Mailbox -Identity "$UserEmailAddress" | %{$_.Alias}
New-InboxRule -Name $MoveToFolder -Mailbox $UserEmailAddress -FromAddressContainsWords $FromAddressContainsWords -MoveToFolder ${'$MAlias:\Inbox\$MoveToFolder'}
Remove-PSSession $Session
```

Comment: Down-voted because??

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I don't need any of you! This time... Fixed the broken parameter and all is well now.

```
-MoveToFolder "$($UserEmailAddress):\$MoveToFolder"
```